# datatables and jQuery UI accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-accordion

I have some accordions on my page, inside of them are tables. I want to use jQuery datatables but only the basic tables without buttons and search field are shown.

If I use datatables outside the accordion, it works fine.

I think the datatables get overwritten because they appear for about a second when I open a new accordion.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Edit: here is some of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    create: function(e,ui) {
        loadList();  

    },
    beforeActivate: function(e, ui) {
        switch(ui.newHeader.next().attr("id")){
            case "list": { 

                loadList();
                $('.tablesort').dataTable();

                break;
            }
            case "add": { 
                loadAdd();
                break;

            default: {
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The content of the accordion is being loaded with loadList and loadAdd

Comment: some of your code will be helpful =)